# How to Create an Oracle Trigger to Dynamically Group/Queue Processes Based on Status?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, queue, jobs

Need help with the following based on the example below (with utilizing triggers and sequences):

I have a Reference table (t2) with columns seq.nextval as queue_num,sysdate,status (PROCESSING/COMPLETED/FAILED) that when Source (t1) is loaded new data, the trigger will pick up the newly inserted record and load that to the reference table (t2) and mark it with status PROCESSING and with seq.nextval as queue_num.

What I am having trouble figuring out is we only have 5 servers max and each server can only handle at most 20 PROCESSING status jobs. How would I create triggers that will load the data across the 5 servers with a 20 record max for each server, and then when it reaches its max any other records that still need to be loaded will load once one of the PROCESSING jobs in QUEUE turns to COMPLETED?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

> "How would I create triggers that will load the data across the 5 servers "

Probably you wouldn't. Pushing work from `T1` is a bad idea precisely because there is no way to regulate the flow based on the state of `T2`.

Rather you should have background processes - jobs - which poll `T1` for new records, grab some (20?) and work on them, perhaps populating `T2` (if that's still required, not sure what your actual process architecture looks like). When the 20 records are exhausted the job polls `T1` for some more, and either iterates through the table or goes to sleep.

Obviously this is rather vague but I'm afraid that fits the sketchiness of the question. Please free free to elaborate your question with more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. What I am trying to accomplish is the following example:

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. What I am trying to accomplish is the following example:

Job starts showing the following:

ROW_ID |  STATUS       |NAME
-------------------------------
 1 | PROCESSING | SCOTT 
 2 | PROCESSING | JAMES
 3 | PROCESSING | PAUL
 4 | PROCESSING | MIKE
 5 | PROCESSING | JOHN
-------------------------------
 6 | IN_QUEUE      | SARA
 7 | IN_QUEUE      | LARRY
 8 | IN_QUEUE      | DAVID
 9 | IN_QUEUE      | MARIA
 10 | IN_QUEUE      | TED

Comment: * What I need is something to dynamically call the next record "IN_QUEUE" and populate it as a "PROCESSING" STATUS when one of the current running status changes to "COMPLETED" or "FAILED" as shown below:

Comment: Job #1(SCOTT) completes and next IN_QUEUE populates to PROCESSING:
ROW_ID |  STATUS       |NAME
-------------------------------
 1 | PROCESSING | JAMES 
 2 | PROCESSING | PAUL
 3 | PROCESSING | MIKE
 4 | PROCESSING | JOHN
 5 | PROCESSING | SARA
-------------------------------
 6 | IN_QUEUE      | LARRY
 7 | IN_QUEUE      | DAVID
 8 | IN_QUEUE      | MARIA
 9 | IN_QUEUE      | TED
 10 | COMPLETED     | SCOTT

Comment: Job #3(MIKE) completes this time and next IN_QUEUE populates to PROCESSING:
ROW_ID |  STATUS       |NAME
-------------------------------
 1 | PROCESSING | JAMES 
 2 | PROCESSING | PAUL
 3 | PROCESSING | JOHN
 4 | PROCESSING | SARA
 5 | PROCESSING | LARRY
-------------------------------
 6 | IN_QUEUE      | DAVID
 7 | IN_QUEUE      | MARIA
 8 | IN_QUEUE      | TED
 9 | COMPLETED     | MIKE
 10 | COMPLETED     | SCOTT

Comment: I tried something like this, but dont think the logic is correct, plus mutating errors :-(

Main thing is to dynamically populate the column from IN_QUEUE to PROCESSING once any one of the jobs completes

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "STGDATALOAD"."EVERGREEN_REF_TRIG" 
BEFORE update on STGDATALOAD.EVERGREEN_REF
for each row 
 WHEN ((old.STATUS = 'IN_QUEUE' AND old.WORKFLOW IS NOT NULL AND new.WORKFLOW is NULL) AND (new.STATUS = 'COMPLETED' or new.STATUS = 'FAILED'))

Comment: begin 
:new.QUEUE := EVERGREEN_SEQ.nextval;
:new.OS_USER := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER');
:new.DB_USER := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_USER');
:new.SCHEMA := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA');
:new.HOST_NAME := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','HOST');
:new.IP_ADDRESS := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS');
:new.APP_NAME := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','MODULE');
:new.STATUS := 'PROCESSING';
:new.WORKFLOW := :old.WORKFLOW;
:new.START_TIME := SYSTIMESTAMP;
COMMIT;
end;
/

Comment: Seriously dude, please **edit your question** to include more information. This is unreadable.